# Command Timeout being ignored

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, timeout, database-connection

I use this function to check that the connection to the database server works, I've set a timeout of 3 seconds, but when the server is not available, it takes about 45 seconds to catch the error. Why is CommandTimeout being ignored?

```cs
bool CheckDbConn()
{
  try
  {
    using (MyDB db=new MyDB(GetCustomConnString()))
    {
      db.Database.CommandTimeout = 3;
      var someEntity =  db.SomeSet.FirstOrDefault();
      return true; // connection ok
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   // catches error after 45 seconds
   return false; // error connecting server;
  }
}
```

- Entity Framework 6.2

Comment: Seems what you need is, e.g. for SQL server, [ConnectionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionTimeout)

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks, it works, are you going to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [ConnectionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionTimeout)

CommandTimeout if for limiting how long your command runs.

Comment: Key thing here, is that you HAVE TO ADD IT to the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Justin's answer,

This property is readonly, you have to add it to the conn string

```cs
static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
        + "Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30";
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionTimeout